# combox value not showing after loading vba

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a MS Access form to enter purchase orders. It is a main form with the general order details- supplier name, date and then a subform in datasheet view where the user puts in the actual items ordered. The first field in the subform- is a combobox to choose the item, the next field is the amount ordered and then the price and total fields are calculated automatically.

I wanted the combobox to only show items belonging to the supplier selected on the main form. I did this successfully with the following code

```
Private Sub CmbSupplier_Change()

 Me!sfrmOrderDetail.Form!CmbItem.RowSource = "SELECT Items.ID, Items.Product, " _
                                           & "       Items.Supplier" _
                                           & " FROM tblItems" _ 
                                           & " WHERE ((Items.Supplier)= " _
                                                       & Me.CmbSupplier & ");"

End Sub
```

I put this also into the `Form_Current()` event- so it should redo it when I change to a new record.

However after putting in a few orders, I went back to the previous order with the forms back button to check something I entered and I saw that while the rest of the info remained, the `items` field (the combobox) on the first record of the subform was empty. Any additional rows- were filled in. When I go into that empty field with my cursor it 'refreshes' and fills in the value.

Just so I'm clear, for example, my first order supplier is *Staples*. I have three rows in my subfrom - *ink* , *stapler*, *paper*. After leaving the record and coming back in, the following occurs:

1. The *ink* is not showing, though *stapler* and *paper* are as well as the quantity of ink, price and total.
2. When I press in the field, it suddenly shows and I can see the combobox list which has the correct items listed so the code definitely worked.

Comment: This is a lot of text without actually getting to the point. Where is the problem? Does the table `tblItems` not contain the desired data? Does that table contain the data, but `CmbItem` isn't showing the entries after you set the `RowSource` property? Does this work but the event handler isn't called when expected, so the combobox never gets refreshed? Please isolate the error and update your question so it is more specific as to where and how we can help.

Comment: should it be in Access, it'd better be there the corresponding tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that what happens here:

- You move back to an existing record
- Access tries to show the previously entered item in the combobox, but can't, because the value is not part of the combobox rowsource
- Then `Form_Current` runs and changes the Rowsource to the current supplier
- but `CmbItem` doesn't pick that up until you click into it.

Solution should be to add a

```
Me!sfrmOrderDetail.Form!CmbItem.Refresh
```

after changing the Rowsource.

Comment: Thanks! that explains what was happening! Thanks for explaining and the refresh did the trick.